# Android Bluetooth pairing. How to detect I entered wrong PIN from my APP?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im making an Android app, that connects with BLE devices. I have almost finished my APP, just this one last BUG.

When I connect with a new device, and it asks me for a PIN, if I enter it incorrect it just freezes.
I have checked out other Android Apps that work with Bluetooth, but they also seem not fixed this problem.

For example Zentri - BLE Commander, it just has a popup that says you have to use Android Settings for pairing.

Another: Google example App (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt) , It doesn't  freeze like mine does, but it doesn't pop up anything, just like nothing happened.

So is it even possible to detect that user entered a wrong pairing PIN ? If it is , help me out here.

Edit: 
Thanks to Michael. I fixed the problem I had earlier.

```
int state =(bluetoothDevice.getBondState());
while (state == 11) {
    // 11 = BOND_BONDING
    // Stay's here while it tries to bond.
    state = bluetoothDevice.getBondState();
}
if(state == 10) {
    // 10 = BOND_NONE
    // If it failed to bond
}
if(state == 12) {
    // 12 = BOND_BONDED
    // If it bonded
}
```

It works well. Just when User click off the screen, it goes in background and my app still waiting for state to change. User has to wait about 20 seconds then the app becomes active again.

Comment: Do you listen for `ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED`? If the state goes from `BOND_BONDING` to `BOND_NONE` then the pairing failed for whatever reason and you'll have to retry if you still want to pair.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Your comment helped me to get the answer. I never thought of searching for word "Bond" instead of "Pair/Pairing". 
I'm using similar method to fix this problem bluetoothDevice.getBondState()